# need to refresh to show local storage values in javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I'm trying to get the values stored in the local storage variables in order to display them !! 
but the problem here is that the display of the values is immediate, in other words :
the first time of loading the page nothing is displayed then every time i refresh the page the next value is displayed.

```
function ChoixDeQuestion (){

var ide=window.sessionStorage.getItem('idenq');
GetQuest(10);//--> this function store some values in the 'questions' var
var storedQuest=JSON.parse(window.localStorage['questions']);
var i;

for ( i = 0; i < storedQuest.length; i++) 
    {
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
 switch(storedQuest[i].type) {
      case 'text':
           newdiv.innerHTML += "<br> Question " + (i + 1) + " : "+storedQuest[i].text+" ?  <br><br><textarea name='quest"+(i + 1)+"' rows=4 cols=40 >type here...</textarea>" ;

           break;
      case 'simple':
           var questId=storedQuest[i].id;
           GetChoix(questId);
           var storedChoix=JSON.parse(window.localStorage['choices'+questId]);

           newdiv.innerHTML += "<br> Question " + (i + 1) + " : "+storedQuest[i].text+" ? <br><br>";
           for (var j = 0; j < storedChoix.length; j++) {
           newdiv.innerHTML += "  " + (j + 1) +"- "+storedChoix[j].text+ " <input type='radio' name='choix"+(j + 1)+"'>";

           }
           break;
      case 'multiple':
           var questId=storedQuest[i].id;
           GetChoix(questId);
           var storedChoix=JSON.parse(window.localStorage['choices'+questId]);

           newdiv.innerHTML += "<br> Question " + (i + 1) + " : "+storedQuest[i].text+" ? <br><br>";
           for (var j = 0; j < storedChoix.length; j++) {
           newdiv.innerHTML += " " + (j + 1) +"- "+storedChoix[j].text+ " <input type='checkbox' name='choix"+(j + 1)+"'>";

            } 
            break;
 document.getElementById('results').appendChild(newdiv);

    }
 }
```

thie method is called in the

```
 $(document).ready(function() { ChoixDeQuestion();});
```

So how can I get all the values shown in the same time when the page is loaded ??